# How to change the properties of a sticky up arrow button based on its position?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sticky, sticky-footer

I have a sticky up arrow image for my webpage as follows:

HTML:

```
<a href = "#navbar-scroll"><img src = "images/sticky-btn-light.png" id = "myBtn" alt = "sticky-up-button"></a>
```

And CSS:

```
#myBtn {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 50px; 
    right: 30px; 
    z-index: 99; 
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 15px; 
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 5%;
    opacity: 0.5 ;
}
```

The button disappears when the user scrolls down and appears when the user scrolls up based on this JS code.

```
window.onscroll = function(e) {
    console.log(this.oldScroll > this.scrollY);
    if((this.scrollY == 0) || (this.oldScroll < this.scrollY)  ){
        document.getElementById('myBtn').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
    else if(this.oldScroll > this.scrollY){
        document.getElementById('myBtn').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
    this.oldScroll = this.scrollY;
}
```

Now, I want to change the color of the button based on its changing position on the screen. As I scroll the page, the sticky button will be in different sections as below.[image: Web page layout1]
If the sticky button is in Section A, it should be red. And if it is in Section B, it should be blue.[image: Web page layout2] Please note that it's the page that is moving, not the button. The button is in a fixed position.

For this, I need the id of the section in which the sticky button is overlapping at any given moment. Is there any way to get that information through JavaScript?

PS: I have adjusted the details to make things more clear. It's the page that is moving. So, if I use `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` for `#myBtn`, will I not get the same top/y values for that element wherever I scroll on the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to get the x,y of the top left corner and the x,y of the bottom right corner of a element.

```
var arrow     = document.getElementById('myBtn');
var arrowRect = arrow.getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(arrowRect.top, arrowRect.right, arrowRect.bottom, arrowRect.left);

var section     = document.getElementById('section1');
var sectionRect = section.getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(sectionRect.top, sectionRect.right, sectionRect.bottom, sectionRect.left);
```

Then you can check collisions with the arrow and the section. In your case the x-axis doesn't matter:

```
// This checks if the arrow is touching the section
( arrowRect.bottom > sectionRect.top && arrowRect.top < sectionRect.bottom  )

// This checks if the arrow isn't touching the section, then inverts it (faster)
!( arrowRect.bottom < sectionRect.top || arrowRect.top > sectionRect.bottom )
```

Comment: The button is in a fixed position. So, if I used Element.getBoundingClientRect(), will I not get the same values of top/Y whenever I scroll?

Comment: Ok, I got it. The button's position will always be fixed, but the sections' position will keep on changing whenever I scroll. Great. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The coordinates are relative to the viewport. Here's a page explaining different coordinate systems in more detail https://javascript.info/coordinates I know you've figured it out, but I thought I would link that for future reference :)

Answer (score 1):

Here, I did an example for you to test and implement.

this will also help understand `getBoundingClientRect` even with fixed position

```js
var arrow= document.getElementById('myBtn');
window.onscroll = function(e) {
    var arrowBound = arrow.getBoundingClientRect();
    var divs = document.querySelectorAll(".container > div");
    divs.forEach(function(item){
      var divBound = item.getBoundingClientRect();
      var color= item.getAttribute("arrowColor");
      if ( arrowBound.bottom > divBound.top && arrowBound.top < divBound.bottom  )
      {
        arrow.style.borderTopColor  = color
      }
    })
}
```

```css
#myBtn {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px; 
    left:270px;
    z-index: 99; 
    cursor: pointer;
  width: 0; 
  height: 0; 
  border-left: 20px solid transparent;
  border-right: 20px solid transparent;
  
  border-top: 20px solid #f00;
}

.container{
width:300px;
height:800px;
  z-index: 81;
}

.container > div {
width:300px;
height:100px;
border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<a  id = "myBtn" href = "#navbar-scroll"></a>

<div arrowColor="red"> box red </div>

<div arrowColor="blue"> box blue </div>


<div arrowColor="green"> box green </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Np, glad i could help. Dont forget to mark this as answer if it really is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can get coords of a html element with getBoundingClientRect() method, call this function and you'll get the Y coords of element (pixels), then you can use an if conditional

```js
function getCoords(elem) {
  let box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  let body = document.body;
  let docEl = document.documentElement;
  let scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || docEl.scrollTop || body.scrollTop;
  let clientTop = docEl.clientTop || body.clientTop || 0;
  return Math.round(box.top +  scrollTop - clientTop);
}

if(getCoords(elem) > 100){
    elem.className = 'your_class_name'
}
```

```css
.your_class_name{
            color: red;
        }
```

Comment: I think the description was not clear enough. The page is moving, the button is in a fixed position. So, if I use Element.getBoundingClientRect(), the values of top/Y for that button will be the same regardless of where I have scrolled. Please correct me if I am wrong. Also, I have made some edits in the question itself to make it clearer.